# Ogre3D and SkyX - Can't get SkyX to work properly

Tags: c++, c, add-on, ogre, ogre3d

I have been trying to get SkyX to work for a while now but couldn't succeed. Here is my code:

```
//THESE ARE GLOBAL
SkyX::BasicController* skyBasicController = NULL;
SkyX::SkyX* mSkyX = NULL;
Ogre::Camera* camera;
...

    Ogre::SceneManager *sceneManager = ogreMain.getRoot()->createSceneManager(
            Ogre::ST_GENERIC, "MainSceneManager");
    Ogre::SceneNode *rootSceneNode = sceneManager->getRootSceneNode();

    Ogre::ResourceGroupManager& resGrpMgr =
            Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::getSingleton();

    Ogre::String terrainResGrpName = "Terrain";
    resGrpMgr.createResourceGroup(terrainResGrpName);
    resGrpMgr.addResourceLocation(".\\Media\\Terrain\\programs", "FileSystem",
            terrainResGrpName, 0);
    resGrpMgr.addResourceLocation(".\\Media\\Terrain\\scripts", "FileSystem",
            terrainResGrpName, 0);
    resGrpMgr.addResourceLocation(".\\Media\\Terrain\\textures", "FileSystem",
            terrainResGrpName, 0);

    // The function 'initialiseResourceGroup' parses scripts if any in the locations.
    resGrpMgr.initialiseResourceGroup(terrainResGrpName);

    // Files that can be loaded are loaded.
    resGrpMgr.loadResourceGroup(terrainResGrpName);

    Ogre::String skyResGrpName = "SkyX";
    resGrpMgr.createResourceGroup(skyResGrpName);
    resGrpMgr.addResourceLocation(".\\Media\\SkyX", "FileSystem", skyResGrpName,
            0);

    // The function 'initialiseResourceGroup' parses scripts if any in the locations.
    resGrpMgr.initialiseResourceGroup(skyResGrpName);

    // Files that can be loaded are loaded.
    resGrpMgr.loadResourceGroup(skyResGrpName);

    ogreMain.getWindow()->setActive(true);
    ogreMain.getWindow()->setAutoUpdated(false);
    sceneManager->setAmbientLight(Ogre::ColourValue(.6, .6, .6));
    sceneManager->setShadowTechnique(SHADOWTYPE_STENCIL_ADDITIVE);
    sceneManager->setShadowColour(ColourValue(0, 0, 0));

    camera = sceneManager->createCamera();

    Ogre::SceneNode *camera_node = player_node->createChildSceneNode();
    camera_node->attachObject(camera);
    float viewport_width = 1.0f;
    float viewport_height = 1.0f;
    float viewport_left = (1.0f - viewport_width) * 0.5f;
    float viewport_top = (1.0f - viewport_height) * 0.5f;
    unsigned short lMainViewportZOrder = 100;
    Ogre::Viewport *vp = ogreMain.getWindow()->addViewport(camera,
    lMainViewportZOrder, viewport_left, viewport_top, viewport_width,
        viewport_height);

    vp->setAutoUpdated(true);
    //vp->setBackgroundColour(Ogre::ColourValue(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f));

    float ratio = float(vp->getActualWidth()) / float(vp->getActualHeight());
    camera->setAspectRatio(ratio);

    camera->setNearClipDistance(1.5f);
    camera->setFarClipDistance(50000);

    camera->setPosition(0, 6, 26);
    camera->setDirection(0, -1, -6.5f);
...

    skyBasicController = new SkyX::BasicController();
    mSkyX = new SkyX::SkyX(sceneManager, skyBasicController);
    mSkyX->create();
    mSkyX->getVCloudsManager()->getVClouds()->setDistanceFallingParams(
            Ogre::Vector2(2, -1));
    ogreMain.getRoot()->addFrameListener(mSkyX);
    ogreMain.getWindow()->addListener(mSkyX);

    setPreset(mPresets[3]);

    ogreMain.getRoot()->clearEventTimes();

... //some var declarations, then main loop

//BELOW HERE IS TAKEN FROM 2ND DEMO

struct SkyXSettings
{
    /** Constructor
        @remarks Skydome + vol. clouds + lightning settings
     */
    SkyXSettings(const Ogre::Vector3 t, const Ogre::Real& tm, const Ogre::Real& mp, const SkyX::AtmosphereManager::Options& atmOpt,
        const bool& lc, const bool& vc, const Ogre::Real& vcws, const bool& vcauto, const Ogre::Radian& vcwd, 
        const Ogre::Vector3& vcac, const Ogre::Vector4& vclr,  const Ogre::Vector4& vcaf, const Ogre::Vector2& vcw,
        const bool& vcl, const Ogre::Real& vclat, const Ogre::Vector3& vclc, const Ogre::Real& vcltm)
        : time(t), timeMultiplier(tm), moonPhase(mp), atmosphereOpt(atmOpt), layeredClouds(lc), volumetricClouds(vc), vcWindSpeed(vcws)
        , vcAutoupdate(vcauto), vcWindDir(vcwd), vcAmbientColor(vcac), vcLightResponse(vclr), vcAmbientFactors(vcaf), vcWheater(vcw)
        , vcLightnings(vcl), vcLightningsAT(vclat), vcLightningsColor(vclc), vcLightningsTM(vcltm)
    {}

    /** Constructor
        @remarks Skydome + vol. clouds
     */
    SkyXSettings(const Ogre::Vector3 t, const Ogre::Real& tm, const Ogre::Real& mp, const SkyX::AtmosphereManager::Options& atmOpt,
        const bool& lc, const bool& vc, const Ogre::Real& vcws, const bool& vcauto, const Ogre::Radian& vcwd, 
        const Ogre::Vector3& vcac, const Ogre::Vector4& vclr,  const Ogre::Vector4& vcaf, const Ogre::Vector2& vcw)
        : time(t), timeMultiplier(tm), moonPhase(mp), atmosphereOpt(atmOpt), layeredClouds(lc), volumetricClouds(vc), vcWindSpeed(vcws)
        , vcAutoupdate(vcauto), vcWindDir(vcwd), vcAmbientColor(vcac), vcLightResponse(vclr), vcAmbientFactors(vcaf), vcWheater(vcw), vcLightnings(false)
    {}

    /** Constructor
        @remarks Skydome settings
     */
    SkyXSettings(const Ogre::Vector3 t, const Ogre::Real& tm, const Ogre::Real& mp, const SkyX::AtmosphereManager::Options& atmOpt, const bool& lc)
        : time(t), timeMultiplier(tm), moonPhase(mp), atmosphereOpt(atmOpt), layeredClouds(lc), volumetricClouds(false), vcLightnings(false)
    {}

    /// Time
    Ogre::Vector3 time;
    /// Time multiplier
    Ogre::Real timeMultiplier;
    /// Moon phase
    Ogre::Real moonPhase;
    /// Atmosphere options
    SkyX::AtmosphereManager::Options atmosphereOpt;
    /// Layered clouds?
    bool layeredClouds;
    /// Volumetric clouds?
    bool volumetricClouds;
    /// VClouds wind speed
    Ogre::Real vcWindSpeed;
    /// VClouds autoupdate
    bool vcAutoupdate;
    /// VClouds wind direction
    Ogre::Radian vcWindDir;
    /// VClouds ambient color
    Ogre::Vector3 vcAmbientColor;
    /// VClouds light response
    Ogre::Vector4 vcLightResponse;
    /// VClouds ambient factors
    Ogre::Vector4 vcAmbientFactors;
    /// VClouds wheater
    Ogre::Vector2 vcWheater;
    /// VClouds lightnings?
    bool vcLightnings;
    /// VClouds lightnings average aparition time
    Ogre::Real vcLightningsAT;
    /// VClouds lightnings color
    Ogre::Vector3 vcLightningsColor;
    /// VClouds lightnings time multiplier
    Ogre::Real vcLightningsTM;
};

/** Demo presets
    @remarks The best way of determinate each parameter value is by using a real-time editor.
             These presets have been quickly designed using the Paradise Editor, which is a commercial solution.
             At the time I'm writting these lines, SkyX 0.1 is supported by Ogitor. Hope that the Ogitor team will 
             support soon SkyX 0.3, this way you all are going to be able to quickly create cool SkyX configurations.
 */
SkyXSettings mPresets[] = {
    // Sunset
    SkyXSettings(Ogre::Vector3(8.85f, 7.5f, 20.5f),  -0.08f, 0, SkyX::AtmosphereManager::Options(9.77501f, 10.2963f, 0.01f, 0.0022f, 0.000675f, 30, Ogre::Vector3(0.57f, 0.52f, 0.44f), -0.991f, 3, 4), false, true, 300, false, Ogre::Radian(270), Ogre::Vector3(0.63f,0.63f,0.7f), Ogre::Vector4(0.35, 0.2, 0.92, 0.1), Ogre::Vector4(0.4, 0.7, 0, 0), Ogre::Vector2(0.8,1)),
    // Clear
    SkyXSettings(Ogre::Vector3(17.16f, 7.5f, 20.5f), 0, 0, SkyX::AtmosphereManager::Options(9.77501f, 10.2963f, 0.01f, 0.0017f, 0.000675f, 30, Ogre::Vector3(0.57f, 0.54f, 0.44f), -0.991f, 2.5f, 4), false),
    // Thunderstorm 1
    SkyXSettings(Ogre::Vector3(12.23, 7.5f, 20.5f),  0, 0, SkyX::AtmosphereManager::Options(9.77501f, 10.2963f, 0.01f, 0.00545f, 0.000375f, 30, Ogre::Vector3(0.55f, 0.54f, 0.52f), -0.991f, 1, 4), false, true, 300, false, Ogre::Radian(0), Ogre::Vector3(0.63f,0.63f,0.7f), Ogre::Vector4(0.25, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1), Ogre::Vector4(0.45, 0.3, 0.6, 0.1), Ogre::Vector2(1,1), true, 0.5, Ogre::Vector3(1,0.976,0.92), 2),
    // Thunderstorm 2
    SkyXSettings(Ogre::Vector3(10.23, 7.5f, 20.5f),  0, 0, SkyX::AtmosphereManager::Options(9.77501f, 10.2963f, 0.01f, 0.00545f, 0.000375f, 30, Ogre::Vector3(0.55f, 0.54f, 0.52f), -0.991f, 0.5, 4), false, true, 300, false, Ogre::Radian(0), Ogre::Vector3(0.63f,0.63f,0.7f), Ogre::Vector4(0, 0.02, 0.34, 0.24), Ogre::Vector4(0.29, 0.3, 0.6, 1), Ogre::Vector2(1,1), true, 0.5, Ogre::Vector3(0.95,1,1), 2),
    // Desert
    SkyXSettings(Ogre::Vector3(7.59f, 7.5f, 20.5f), 0, -0.8f, SkyX::AtmosphereManager::Options(9.77501f, 10.2963f, 0.01f, 0.0072f, 0.000925f, 30, Ogre::Vector3(0.71f, 0.59f, 0.53f), -0.997f, 2.5f, 1), true),
    // Night
    SkyXSettings(Ogre::Vector3(21.5f, 7.5, 20.5), 0.03, -0.25, SkyX::AtmosphereManager::Options(), true)
};

void setPreset(const SkyXSettings& preset)
{
    mSkyX->setTimeMultiplier(preset.timeMultiplier);
    mBasicController->setTime(preset.time);
    mBasicController->setMoonPhase(preset.moonPhase);
    mSkyX->getAtmosphereManager()->setOptions(preset.atmosphereOpt);

    // Layered clouds
    if (preset.layeredClouds)
    {
        // Create layer cloud
        if (mSkyX->getCloudsManager()->getCloudLayers().empty())
        {
            mSkyX->getCloudsManager()->add(SkyX::CloudLayer::Options(/* Default options */));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Remove layer cloud
        if (!mSkyX->getCloudsManager()->getCloudLayers().empty())
        {
            mSkyX->getCloudsManager()->removeAll();
        }
    }

    mSkyX->getVCloudsManager()->setWindSpeed(preset.vcWindSpeed);
    mSkyX->getVCloudsManager()->setAutoupdate(preset.vcAutoupdate);

    SkyX::VClouds::VClouds* vclouds = mSkyX->getVCloudsManager()->getVClouds();

    vclouds->setWindDirection(preset.vcWindDir);
    vclouds->setAmbientColor(preset.vcAmbientColor);
    vclouds->setLightResponse(preset.vcLightResponse);
    vclouds->setAmbientFactors(preset.vcAmbientFactors);
    vclouds->setWheater(preset.vcWheater.x, preset.vcWheater.y, false);

    if (preset.volumetricClouds)
    {
        // Create VClouds
        if (!mSkyX->getVCloudsManager()->isCreated())
        {
            // SkyX::MeshManager::getSkydomeRadius(...) works for both finite and infinite(=0) camera far clip distances
            mSkyX->getVCloudsManager()->create(mSkyX->getMeshManager()->getSkydomeRadius(mRenderingCamera));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Remove VClouds
        if (mSkyX->getVCloudsManager()->isCreated())
        {
            mSkyX->getVCloudsManager()->remove();
        }
    }

    vclouds->getLightningManager()->setEnabled(preset.vcLightnings);
    vclouds->getLightningManager()->setAverageLightningApparitionTime(preset.vcLightningsAT);
    vclouds->getLightningManager()->setLightningColor(preset.vcLightningsColor);
    vclouds->getLightningManager()->setLightningTimeMultiplier(preset.vcLightningsTM);

    //mTextArea->setCaption(buildInfoStr());

    // Reset camera position/orientation
    //mRenderingCamera->setPosition(0,0,0);
    //mRenderingCamera->setDirection(0,0,1);

    mSkyX->update(0);
}
```

I am not using ExampleApplication framework or any other framework. I have wrtitten my own small class with my needs.

I can only see lightnings and they seem to be too close compared to demos. Also, all the lightnings' origin is constantly at the top of the camera, moving with it.

I only have a few boxes and a camera attached to one of them in my scene.

I have compiled SkyX 0.3.1 as seperate DLL, with the same boost and ogre libraries(with the application, all conf'ed as debug) as debug conf' set.

Debug output mentioning SkyX follows as:

```
Creating resource group Terrain
Added resource location '.\Media\Terrain\programs' of type 'FileSystem' to resource group 'Terrain'
Added resource location '.\Media\Terrain\scripts' of type 'FileSystem' to resource group 'Terrain'
Added resource location '.\Media\Terrain\textures' of type 'FileSystem' to resource group 'Terrain'
Initialising resource group Terrain
Parsing scripts for resource group Terrain
Parsing script Terrain.material
Finished parsing scripts for resource group Terrain
Creating resources for group Terrain
All done
Loading resource group 'Terrain' - Resources: 1 World Geometry: 1
Texture: TerrainAmbientMap.jpg: Loading 1 faces(PF_L8,512x512x1) Internal format is PF_L8,512x512x1.
Texture: TerrainTex0.jpg: Loading 1 faces(PF_R8G8B8,512x512x1) Internal format is PF_X8R8G8B8,512x512x1.
Texture: TerrainTex1.jpg: Loading 1 faces(PF_R8G8B8,512x512x1) Internal format is PF_X8R8G8B8,512x512x1.
Finished loading resource group Terrain
Creating resource group SkyX
Added resource location '.\Media\SkyX' of type 'FileSystem' to resource group 'SkyX'
Initialising resource group SkyX
Parsing scripts for resource group SkyX
Parsing script SkyX.material
Finished parsing scripts for resource group SkyX
Creating resources for group SkyX
All done
Loading resource group 'SkyX' - Resources: 1 World Geometry: 1
Texture: Noise.jpg: Loading 1 faces(PF_R8G8B8,1024x1024x1) Internal format is PF_X8R8G8B8,1024x1024x1.
Texture: SkyX_Starfield.png: Loading 1 faces(PF_A8R8G8B8,512x512x1) Internal format is PF_A8R8G8B8,512x512x1.
Texture: SkyX_Moon.png: Loading 1 faces(PF_A8R8G8B8,512x512x1) Internal format is PF_A8R8G8B8,512x512x1.
Texture: SkyX_MoonHalo.png: Loading 1 faces(PF_A8R8G8B8,512x256x1) Internal format is PF_A8R8G8B8,512x256x1.
Finished loading resource group SkyX
...

Can't assign material _NULL_ to SubEntity of SkyXMeshEnt because this Material does not exist. Have you forgotten to define it in a .material script?
[SkyX] VClouds warning: unregistered camera registered, manual unregistering is needed before camera destruction
```

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like whatever exported your model didn't fill out the mesh definition correctly and/or competely.  Somewhere in the mesh file there's a missing reference to a required material or other effect.

Comment: Yeah but I have directly copied materials folder of the demo. That should have what is needed. I load SkyX and Terrain folders inside that demo's meterials folder.

Also, there is the positioning of lightnings problem. So maybe that error saying _\_NULL\__ is normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply removing the following line solved the problem. Apparently shadows don't work with SkyX.

```
sceneManager->setShadowTechnique(SHADOWTYPE_STENCIL_ADDITIVE);
```

You can use that line after SkyX initialization though, but I don't know if it works or not.